# Осуществление соединения между back и front (проблема с ssl)

Tags: ssl, https

Делаю проект с front и back частями. Front - HTML, CSS, JS. Back - Node.JS (Koa). Для фронта у меня есть рабочий SSL сертификат.

При тестировании функционала на localhost проблем не возникло, но при переносе на хостинг появилась большая проблема. Из-за того, что соединение фронта с бэком происходит по http протоколу, на фронте появляется ошибка *mixed content blocking*. Я  добавил бэку самоподписаный SSL сертификат. На ПК всё работает (Но появляется предупреждение о возможной опасности), а на Android устройстве и в Chrome, и в Яндекс запрос на бэк считается небезопасным и отклоняется. (В консоли *net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID*)

Далее я попыталс полностью убрать все SSL сертификаты и перейти на http. Но Яндекс и Google уже промаркировали мой домен как "с SSL соединением" и блокируют любую попытку взода.

Изучив различные материалы я понял, что покупать SSL сертификат для бэка я не буду. Так как у него нет выделенного домена, только IP.

Вопрос: Как мне заставить всю эту систему работать? Желательно без предупреждений и с SSL соединением.

Comment: Никак не могу понять что вы называете фронтом, а что бэком?

Comment: Нужно просто поставить доверенный сертификат от какого-либо УЦ.

Comment: @AlexeyTen Это два разных сервера.

Comment: @user338034 Изучив различные материалы я понял, что покупать SSL сертификат для бэка я не буду. Так как у него нет выделенного домена, только IP.

Comment: Эмм, дык, допустим у Вас есть домен front.ru и SSL сертификат для него. Что мешает создать домен back.front.ru (например) и подписать SSL для него хоть на letsencrypt, хоть через cloudflare, хоть в любом другом месте,, где есть бесплатные SSL ?

Comment: @nobody Спасибо, уже пробую.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Простое, но рабочее решение, предложенное [nobody](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/199545/nobody) в комментарии к вопросу.

Допустим у вас есть домен front.ru и SSL сертификат для него. Создайте поддомен back.front.ru и сделайте с него redirect на ip вашего бекенда сервера. Затем подпишите на этот поддомен бесплатный SSL(letsencrypt, cloudflare и тд) В коде фронтенда обращайтесь к этому поддомену.